# What happens if I plug a 2016 MacBook Pro into itself?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging

[The charging cable on the 2016 MacBook Pro](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLL82AM/A/usb-c-charge-cable-2-m?fnode=8b&fs=f%3Dcharger%26fh%3D4595%252B45d4) is USB-C both ways, allowing me to plug the MacBook into itself. What happens if I do this?

Comment: Please refrain from speculations when adding an answer.

Comment: Since nothing special happens when you connect it to another macbook pro I expect nothing happens when you connect it to itself, I just don't dare to try it with mine :#

Comment: I love this question. At best, nothing good will happen, at worst, something bad will happen. But curiosity is such a powerful human driver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new MacBook Pros have circuitry in all USB-C ports so that the charger can be plugged into any port.

Plugging a two-way USB-C cable will just make the device think that it's charging as technically there is a power source coming from one of the ports into the other.

It doesn't actually charge anything but the reporting is what's making the battery icon show 'charging'.

Comment: ??? So it's charging itself or what?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it to plug the macbook pro 2019 or 2020 (not M1) into it self, showed charging and seemed fine so I undid the connection left it running on my desk came back 2 hours later and now it wont start, so I tried charging it for 2 hours, then I tried all the key combinations with no affect.  About to call apple care will post when I learn more. So more detailed information of circumstances and what I have already tried. My charging cable was getting worn out on near the ports so I put on swapped it with a new C to C just incase it was just a bad charging cable, did not help and I have a firmware password so probably explains why none of the keyboard tricks work and finally I scanned the SSD from my other macbook using a thunderbolt 2 dongle to usb c with no errors in diskutility.

Comment: White this is very interesting, I can’t recommend you to charge any device using USB-C in any other way than the original follow chargers unless specific mention in the instructions. I do wonder what happens when the port gets more adopted. Think many people are going to ruin their stuff by accident do to quick ideas how they can charge

Comment: A little update, it ended up being a completely unrelated issue.  The motherboard more or less died.  It wasn't related to being plugged into itself.  Just coincidence that it died two hours later.

Answer (score 0):

We just tried it with my friends laptop
It charges itself (well... it thinks it does)

Answer (score -3):

It probably will detect it as a short circuit and shut down. I would not do it, if I were you.

Comment: It absolutely wouldn't cause a short circuit.

Comment: I tried it, my macbook became sentient and now thinks it a unicorn!!!! I am so sad senny I didn't take your advice ... hep!